# how to install an older version of PHP libmcrypt?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I need to use RC6 cipher for my project. But, because the installed mcrypt library in my server is mcrypt version 2.5.8, so it's not support for RC6 cipher. As wrote in http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php, RC6 128 bit cipher only supported by libmcrypt 2.2.x and 2.4.x.

I have try to find how to install the mcrypt library version 2.2.x or 2.4.x, but i can't find it.

Does anybody know how to install this older version (libmcrypt 2.2.x or 2.2.4)??

Answer (score 0):

this is the link to the 2.2.4 version:

`ftp://195.134.99.74/pub/crypto/mcrypt/attic/libmcrypt/old/libmcrypt-2.2.4.tar.gz`

remove your mycript:

e.g.:
remove php-mcrypt
remove libmcrypt

install from the new package:

e.g.:

```
cd /usr/local/src
tar -zxvf libmcrypt-2.2.4.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/src/libmcrypt-2.2.4
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Comment: on an x86_64 the configure step failed (v2.2.6).  Edited config.sub to add `x86_64)\nbasic_machine=\`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86_64.*/86_64-pc'\`\nos=-sysv32\n;;\n` (subst \n with newline chars) around line 945 worked for the configure step